# Why it throw error like "did not return a View from onCreateView() or this was called before onCreateView()."?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a problem in my project, there is not any error in my codes, but when I build project, it is throw an error for    `viewPager2 = requireView().findViewById(R.id.vpager)`, I do not know why?, any idea?

```
   class MyFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_my) {

    lateinit var viewPager2: ViewPager2
    lateinit var adapter: VideoAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {


        /**set find id*/
        viewPager2 = requireView().findViewById(R.id.vpager)

        /**set database*/
        val mDataBase = Firebase.database.getReference("videos")

        val options = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<VideoModel>()
            .setQuery(mDataBase,VideoModel::class.java)
            .build()
        /**set adapter*/
        adapter = VideoAdapter(options)
        viewPager2.adapter = adapter

        return view
    }
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        adapter.startListening()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        adapter.stopListening()
    }
}
```

Comment: you should use onViewCreated method instead of onCreateView

Comment: @IR42, tnx so much for ur comment, I change but still same, is it possible u answer the question for onViewCreated?

Comment: remove onCreateVIew completely

Comment: @IR42, update like that 
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        
        /**set find id*/
        viewPager2 = requireView().findViewById(R.id.vpager)

        /**set database*/
        val mDataBase = Firebase.database.getReference("videos")

        val options = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<VideoModel>()
            .setQuery(mDataBase,VideoModel::class.java)
            .build()
        /**set adapter*/
        adapter = VideoAdapter(options)
        viewPager2.adapter = adapter
    }. but still same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

class MyFragment : Fragment() {

```
lateinit var viewPager2: ViewPager2
lateinit var adapter: VideoAdapter

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
```

val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false)

```
    return view
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


    /**set find id*/
    viewPager2 = view.findViewById(R.id.vpager)

    /**set database*/
    val mDataBase = Firebase.database.getReference("videos")

    val options = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<VideoModel>()
        .setQuery(mDataBase,VideoModel::class.java)
        .build()
    /**set adapter*/
    adapter = VideoAdapter(options)
    viewPager2.adapter = adapter


}


override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    adapter.startListening()
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    adapter.stopListening()
}
```

}

Comment: tnx so much, but still same

Comment: Try this 

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {  

 val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false)
        return rootlateinit var viewPager2: ViewPager2
lateinit var adapter: VideoAdapter
}

Answer (score 0):

At `onCreateView` fragment lifecycle step, the view hasn't been created yet.

Best practice would be to move that instantiation logic (including the `VideoAdapter` assignment) inside `onViewCreated`, where it's guaranteed that your view is built and ready to be referenced.

Comment: @Danil Beleza, tnx so uch for ur answer but I still do not understand , can u answer clearly by codes?

Comment: You can check more details in Google's official documentation. I'll leave it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment?hl=en#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)) Hope it helps!